# how to get last date of today in datetime datatype?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005, datetime

**select dateadd(s, -1, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())+1,0))**

when i execute this query, it gives '2012-01-30 23:59:59.000'. I donno how to get it as '2012-01-30 23:59:59.997'. If anybody Know, please say.

thanking you!!!

Comment: `s` is for seconds. `ms` is for milliseconds: [DATEADD()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function.

Comment: [Use. Lower. Boundaries.](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23588/why-do-we-have-to-use-switch-in-table-partitioning)

Answer (score 7):

Why on earth do you need the last possible value of today? Stop using `BETWEEN`; it is much easier (and much more reliable, and consistent across various date/time data types) to use an open ended range:

```
DECLARE @today SMALLDATETIME;

SET @today = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '20000101', GETDATE()), '20000101');

SELECT ... FROM ...
WHERE date_column >= @today
AND date_column < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @today);
```

The problem with what you're doing is that the data type can affect what happens. If the underlying data type is `SMALLDATETIME`, it rounds up; if the underlying data type is `DATETIME` or `DATETIME2`, subtracting a second is *not* going to capture all of the data from that day. This is actually one of my favorite slides in my *T-SQL : Bad Habits and Best Practices* talk. For a lot more details, please read these blog posts:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Bad Habits to Kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: Agreed. And another option is to use `WHERE CAST(date_column AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)`, which has nice hooks to ensure index use.

Comment: I also blogged about some performance impacts of the various approaches today: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime